# Simple Nested handlebar foeach doesnt work

Tags: javascript, express, handlebars.js

This is in node.

```
   app.get('/payees', function(req, res)
   {
     var categoriesPromise = Category.getAllCategories();
     var payeesWhereNullPromise = categoriesPromise.then(function() {
        return Payee.getAllPayeesWhere({categoryId:null})
    })
    payeesWhereNullPromise.then(function(payees) {
        var categories = categoriesPromise.value();
        res.render('payees', {categories: categories, subcategories: [], payees:payees});
    })
});
```

This is in the front end

```
{{#each payees as |payee|}}
    {{#each categories as |category|}}
            category.name
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

If I do them seperately they work perfectly but the moment I place them inside each other nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only access the properties of the array you're looping through within `#each`. With the nested foreach in your example you have the problem that Handlebars tries to find `categories` as object property in the `payees` array. But in your case `categories` is a global variable and therefore won't be found.

But you can do what you want with a Handlebars helper function.

**EDIT:** Here an example of using a handlebar helper function.

Template:

```
 {{#list categories payees}}{{/list}}
```

Node server code:

```
var hbs = require('hbs');
hbs.registerHelper('list', function(categories, payees, options) {
   var out = "";
   // Here you can use standard JavaScript to do whatever you want.
   // Also nested loops are possible.
   // Put the wished HTML into the out variable and it will get rendered 
   // in your template.
   for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
      out += "<div>"+categories[i]+"</div>";
      for (var j = 0; j < payees.length; j++) {
      // and so on
      }
   }
   return out;
});
```

Documentations: https://github.com/pillarjs/hbs http://handlebarsjs.com/

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this. Can you give me an example.I dont even want it to be on my case. I know what helper is but I have no idea what you mean. :( Thank you in advance

Comment: I updated my answer with an example. But have a look at the docs. It's explained there in detail.

Comment: I am just going to add that I think it should be tripple { not double. Double { escapes "<" and ">".

Comment: You're right. Although they also use it with the helper function like that (with 2 braces) in the documentation http://handlebarsjs.com/